# second argument to .addEventListner i.e callback function is being executed without event happening

Tags: javascript

I'm selecting all the elements with class ".calc-button" by .querySelectorAll method. Then appling .forEach on the 'catched' array to .addEventListner but the callback function is being executed without the occurance of event 'clicked'. (Also how can I get the innerHTMl value of each event.target ?)

```js
let calcButton = document.querySelectorAll(".calc-button");

calcButton.forEach((button) => button.addEventListener("click", clicked()));

function clicked() {
  console.log("clicked");
}
```

```css
let calcButton = document.querySelectorAll(".calc-button");

calcButton.forEach((button) => button.addEventListener("click", clicked()));

function clicked() {
  console.log("clicked");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>JS Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="calc">
      <div class="calc-row result">0</div>
      <div class="calc-row">
        <button class="calc-button stretch-2" op>C</button
        ><button class="calc-button">&leftarrow;</button
        ><button class="calc-button op">%</button>
      </div>
      <div class="calc-row">
        <button class="calc-button">1</button
        ><button class="calc-button">2</button
        ><button class="calc-button">3</button
        ><button class="calc-button op">-</button>
      </div>
      <div class="calc-row">
        <button class="calc-button">1</button
        ><button class="calc-button">2</button
        ><button class="calc-button">3</button
        ><button class="calc-button op">x</button>
      </div>
      <div class="calc-row">
        <button class="calc-button">1</button
        ><button class="calc-button">2</button
        ><button class="calc-button">3</button
        ><button class="calc-button op">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="calc-row">
        <button class="calc-button stretch-3">0</button
        ><button class="calc-button op">=</button>
      </div>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is because you have to reference the function. Change your statement to `...addEventListener("click", clicked)...`. Putting the brackets signals that it needs to be executed right then and there, whereas if you put just the name, its reference stays there and it is called whenever it is needed.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon Oh I called it explicitly. Thanks for going throught it. Have a nic time.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon Do you how How to get a textual value of the element which triggered the event?

Comment: You have to add an `event` variable as a function passing parameter, and then call `event.target.value` to get the value of the textbox/input that the event listener is attached to.